# Why does an AJAX call to a different website providing an API not violate the Same-Origin Policy?

Tags: cors, same-origin-policy

I was writing a React JS app, running off from localhost:8080, and then my own website, making AJAX calls to [the API that openweathermap.org provides](https://openweathermap.org/forecast5).

Then it made me wonder, for both localhost:8080 and my website, say www.mysite.com, doesn't the AJAX call to fetch data from http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast violate the Same-Origin Policy?

If the sample is actually hosted on GitHub page, then the AJAX call actually could not go through because GitHub page right now use `https`, while the AJAX call to the API use `http` and cannot be `https`, and it won't get the data.

P.S. it is quite sure that the AJAX wasn't done through JSONP, as I actually saw in the console that the request was made, and the response was just pure JSON data. (so no script tag method was used).

Answer (score 1):

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast sends `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers:

```
$ curl -I http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: openresty
Date: Sat, 01 Apr 2017 02:11:30 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 107
Connection: keep-alive
X-Cache-Key: /data/2.5/forecast?
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS explains what effect those response headers have on browsers—but the gist of it is, if your client-side JavaScript code running in a browser sends a cross-origin request, and the response that comes back includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, then the browser will expose that response to your code. But if the response doesn’t include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, then the browser won’t allow your code to access the response.

Comment: interesting... I thought many people know about the same-origin policy, but not this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header... does it even have a name...

Comment: maybe it is called "CORS"... while Wikipedia says: "In March 2009 the draft was renamed to "Cross-Origin Resource Sharing" and in January 2014 it was accepted as a W3C Recommendation." I wonder in which year did it become widely usable...

Comment: Yeah, “CORS” is the name of the protocol behind all this. As far as when it became widely usable, base CORS support has been in most browser engines since 2009 but IE didn’t support it until IE10 shipped in 2012 with base CORS support. Full CORS support has been in all browsers since 2013 when IE11 first shipped. http://caniuse.com/#search=cors